# Does Jetty 8 HTTPClient support making Comet HTTP connections?

Tags: java, jetty, httpclient, comet

I saw that there are methods "setIdleTimeout()" and "setTimeout()" in Jetty HTTPClient.java class.

If I need to use it to make a connection to a Comet HTTP connection, how should I set it so it won't time out?

Comet: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jetty client does not, however there is a java cometd client that is based on the jetty client that you can use.  It was written by Simone Bordet who is both a jetty committer and project lead for cometd.

http://cometd.org/documentation/cometd-java/client